# How can we provide access to specific Jenkins jobs to the user or team?

Tags: jenkins

I want the developers to access Jenkins and run only particular jobs like build now , through Jenkins UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Role Strategy Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) to accomplish that.

Best regards.